# AttributeError: returns 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe.

[image: Dataframe][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9jz7.jpg)

I need a for loop to evaluate each cell in pandas Col_B to see if it contains the string 'MM'. If it does contain it, I want the entire value of the cell in Col_B to be entered for Col_C.  My desired output would show only the last three rows of Col_C having a value of "500.0MM".  When I run the following code, I get:

Code:

```py
for row in range(total_rows):
if df.iloc[row,1].str.contains('MM'):
    df.iloc[row,2] = df.iloc[row,1]
else:
    pass
```

Error:

```one
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-e4521d65e7b6> in <module>
  1 for row in range(total_rows):
  ----> 2     if df.iloc[row,1].str.contains('MM'):
  3         df.iloc[row,2] = df.iloc[row,1]
  4     else:
  5         pass

  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I have tried converting Col_B to string like below before running the loop, but still get the error.

```
df['Col_B'] = df['Col_B'].astype(str)
```

I realize looping is probably not the most efficient way and using `apply` could be best, but I need it to be a loop for other reasons.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you expect if df.iloc[row,1].str to do?  As the error message says, a srting has no attribute `str`.  I think what you want is simply to use the string you just referenced:

```
if "MM" in df.iloc[row,1]:
```

Comment: Or depending on the circumstance - `df.iloc[row,1].endwith('MM')`.

Comment: @wwii Yes, but that's not equivalent to the apparent purpose of the original code.  `endswith` (you missed an `s`) matches the given data.

Comment: Thanks, @Prune.  This was what I needed and it solved my problem.  My logic was that when I ran df[df['Col_B'].str.contains('MM')] it would return the df filtered on all the fields that contained 'MM'.

Answer (score 0):

`df.iloc[row,1]` already returns the string you need since you specified row and column. Therefore you can just use it without `.str` and you dont need pandas contains() method:

```py
for row in range(total_rows):
if 'MM' in df.iloc[row,1]:
    df.iloc[row,2] = df.iloc[row,1]
else:
    pass
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'`

Comment: Like wwii stated, I get the same error type, but with 'contains'.

Comment: `contains()` is a method from pandas. Since this returns a plain string you need to use python's `in`.